# Замена все ссылок в Wordpress "на лету"

Tags: wordpress, replace

Есть массив из заменяемых ссылок и ссылок для замены.

```
$links_for_replase = array('origin' => array(0 => 'http://site.ru/1.html', 1 => 'http://site.ru/2.html'), 'new' => array(0 => 'http://site2.ru/1.html', 1 => 'http://site2.ru/2.html'));
```

Нужно произвести замены "на лету". Т.е. берем сгенерированный HTML и в нем меняем ссылки.

Как это сделать? И можно это же сделать на уровне плагина (т.к. какой-нибудь хук сделать).

Comment: Смотря где. В контенте поста - есть хук `the_content`

Comment: Но это лишь контент. А мне надо весь HTML. Смысл в том, чтобы и в <head> и в <body> были замены.

Comment: Фильтруйте все соответствующие блоки. Фильтры есть на всё.

Comment: Но как мне узнать все блоки? Должен быть header, footer, content. Шаблоны я вижу, но как их обработать универсально, не зависимо от шаблона - не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
файл:wp-includes/template-loader.php

найти:

```
include( $template );
```

заменить на:

```
include( plugin_dir_path(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myplugin/' ) . 'front.php');
```

И в файле front.php сделать что-то вроде

```html
<?php

    function change_url($data, $urls)
    {

        $urls = explode(",", $urls);
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $url = trim($url);
            $url = explode("?", $url);
            $url = $url[0];
            $parsed_url = parse_url($url);

            $origin_url = $parsed_url['scheme'] . "://" . $parsed_url['host'];
            if ($origin_url == get_home_url()) {

                  $new_url = str_replace(get_home_url() . "/", $my_new_url, $url);
                  $data = str_replace($url, $new_url, $data);

            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function get_include_contents($filename)
    {
        if (is_file($filename)) {
            ob_start();
            include $filename;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        return false;
    }

    $string = get_include_contents($template);

    preg_match_all('/<script [^>]+>/i', $string, $parse_url);
    foreach ($parse_url[0] as $url) {
        preg_match('/<*script [^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $url, $result_element);
        $string = change_url($string, $result_element[1]);

    }

    echo $string;
```